# Generate exe with pyinstaller from a code which uses ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, pyinstaller

I have written a simple code which converts a PDF to JPG with ImageMagick, as it is shown below

```
import os
from wand.color import Color
from wand.image import Image

if __name__ == "__main__":
    source_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "sample.pdf")
    target_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "sample.jpg")

    with Image(filename=source_file) as img:
        img.alpha_channel = False
        img.background_color = Color('white')
        img.resize(600, 870)
        img.format = 'jpeg'
        img.save(filename=target_file)
```

The python app runs, but when I convert it to .exe by command `pyinstaller extract.py` and run the resulting .exe, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\Abouzar\pydev\extract\src\build\cover_extract\out00-PYZ.pyz\wand.color", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\Abouzar\pydev\extract\src\build\cover_extract\out00-PYZ.pyz\wand.api", line 1173, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Abouzar\pydev\extract\src\build\cover_extract\out00-PYZ.pyz\ctypes", line 365, in __init__
WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: It should be `os.getcwd()` not `os.getcwd`. I'm surprised that worked at all.

Comment: @rth actually it was getcwd() in my python code, I just paste a wrong copy from the code and the error output here. I put the correct lines instead.